# Extract JSON response data only visible in Network>XHR > angular response

Tags: python, json, angularjs

Thanks in advance for looking into this query.

I am trying to extract data from the `angular` response which is not visible in the HTML code using the inspect function of Chrome browser.

I researched and looked for solutions and have been able to find the data in the `Network (tab)>Fetch/XHR>Response` (screenshots) and also wrote code based on the knowledge I gained researching this topic.
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFg19.jpg)

In order to read the response I am trying the below code by passing the parameters and cookies grabbed from the main [URL](https://www.barchart.com/etfs-funds/performance/percent-change/advances?viewName=main&timeFrame=5d&orderBy=percentChange&orderDir=desc)
and passing them into the request via the below code segment from the main code shared further below. The parameters were created based on information I found under tab `Network (tab)>Fetch/XHR>Header`

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 
             'https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/quotes/get?' + urlencode(params),
             headers=headers
            )
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. Please help confirm what am I missing or doing wrong? I want to read and store the json response what should I be doing?
   [JSON to be extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLnm4.jpg)
2. Also is there a way to read the params using a function?, instead of assigning them as I have done below. What I mean is similar to what I have done for cookies (headers = x.cookies.get_dict()) is there a way to read and assign parameters?

Below is the full code I am using.

```
import requests
import urllib3
from urllib.parse import urlencode

url  = 'https://www.barchart.com/etfs-funds/performance/percent-change/advances?viewName=main&timeFrame=5d&orderBy=percentChange5d&orderDir=desc'

header = {'accept': 'application/json', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'} 

s = requests.Session()
x = s.get(url, headers=header)

headers = x.cookies.get_dict()
params = {    'lists': 'etfs.us.percent.advances.unleveraged.5d',
    'orderDir': 'desc',
    'fields': 'symbol,symbolName,lastPrice,weightedAlpha,percentChangeYtd,percentChange1m,percentChange3m,percentChange1y,symbolCode,symbolType,hasOptions',
    'orderBy': 'percentChange',
    'meta': 'field.shortName,field.type,field.description,lists.lastUpdate',
    'hasOptions': 'true',
    'page': '1',
    'limit': '100',
    'in(leverage%2C(1x))':'',
    'raw': '1'}


http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 
                 'https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/quotes/get?' + urlencode(params),
                 headers=headers
                )
r.data
```

`r.data` response is below, returning an error.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">\n<HTML><HEAD><META
HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;
charset=iso-8859-1">\n<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be
satisfied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>403 ERROR</H1>\n<H2>The request
could not be satisfied.</H2>\n<HR noshade size="1px">\nRequest
blocked.\nWe can\'t connect to the server for this app or website at
this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error.
Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.\n<BR
clear="all">\nIf you provide content to customers through CloudFront,
you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by
reviewing the CloudFront documentation.\n<BR clear="all">\n<HR noshade
size="1px">\n<PRE>\nGenerated by cloudfront (CloudFront)\nRequest ID:
vcjzkFEpvdtf6ihDpy4dVkYx1_lI8SUu3go8mLqJ8MQXR-KRpCvkng==\n</PRE>\n<ADDRESS>\n</ADDRESS>\n</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: have you solved this question?

Comment: No this was not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get reponse by name, on your screenshot name `get?lists=etfs.us` is what you need, you also need to install `playwright`

There is a guide here: https://www.zenrows.com/blog/web-scraping-intercepting-xhr-requests#use-case-nseindiacom

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright 

url = "https://www.barchart.com/etfs-funds/performance/percent-change/advances?viewName=main&timeFrame=5d&orderBy=percentChange5d&orderDir=desc"
with sync_playwright() as p: 
    def handle_response(response): 
        # the endpoint we are insterested in 
        
        if ("get?lists=etfs.us" in response.url): 
            print(response.json())
   
    browser = p.chromium.launch() 
    page = browser.new_page() 
    
    page.on("response", handle_response) 
    page.goto(url, wait_until="networkidle")  
    page.context.close() 
    browser.close()
```

Comment: Oruchkin, thanks for taking the time to respond. I took the necessary steps for playwright to work. Then tried using the above code and also tried the code [link](https://www.zenrows.com/blog/web-scraping-intercepting-xhr-requests#use-case-nseindiacom). In both cases nothing gets returned from the print statement. Am I missing something

Comment: On further investigation I have figured out `def handle_response(response):` function should go through each url in the response and look for the one which has "get?lists=etfs.us" but it seems the response does not provide the urls for the above case and also for the NSE example in the example link. I tried the twitter example and the response does come back with urls. Any idea why the barchart.com and nse.com do not return the urls?

Comment: Try doing every example from the article, you might solve your problem step by step. It should work, at least it is working on my site

Comment: I was getting a 403 error earlier. Had to change the parameter in this line `browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)`, now it returns the desired dataset. Thanks